# How to load a CascadeClassifier using Emgu c#

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I have created my own cascade classifier using opencv_traincascade, i am trying to use it in my C# emgu project but it does not work using HaarCascade. I did some reading and found that CascadeClassifier is required to load xml files obtained through opencv_traincascade, But i could not find the namespace where the class is located. How to use CascadeClassifier in emgu c# project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, you need to use the CascadeClassifier class, the API for this can be found [here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.4.2/document/html/b940bc22-751b-d7bf-e9a4-8798e6f7ccb3.htm)

I shall give you an example using the included HAAR classifier

First, we need to construct a classifier using some of the built in training files. These can be found under the HaarCascades directory in the EmguCV installation directory. We make a new classifier like this:

```
private static readonly CascadeClassifier Classifier = new CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml");
```

This example was taken from [here](http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2013/10/21/face-detection-for-net-using-emgucv/) which shows how to perform Face Detection in EmguCV.