# Resource as a filename

Tags: c#, xml, emgucv

Im using EMGUCV at Visual Studio 2017. I need to set a XML file to a cascadeClassifier like this:

```
CascadeClassifier cascadeClassifier = new CascadeClassifier(@"cascadeClassifier\haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml");
```

Doing this way I need to get a copy of XML file to my Release. So I discover the resource stuff by this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90697/how-to-create-and-use-resources-in-net). So I add the XML to my resource and tried to access it by:

```
CascadeClassifier cascadeClassifier = new CascadeClassifier(Properties.Resources.haarcascade_frontalface_alt2);
```

But this object resource is a string and the CascadeClassifier is expecting a filename, is there a way to do it?

Comment: what is the content of your resource? It should the filename

Comment: The content is a XML. I think when I try to get the resource I'm getting an object, instead a file that EMGU could stream.

Answer (score 1):

Well, according to the API documentation the construction takes in a filename (as you said), but the type of the filename can be a string (must be a string) so there should be no problem when you pass in a string from a resource file/dictionary:
http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.4.2/document/html/b5ce78f6-d5cc-a099-d1a8-25df92564f64.htm

Constructor is:

```
public CascadeClassifier(
    string fileName
)
```

See also this question/answer for an example (without resources used):
[How to load a CascadeClassifier using Emgu c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28415161/how-to-load-a-cascadeclassifier-using-emgu-c-sharp)